# What is the best setting to detect number from speech in google gcp Speech to text api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to detect the numbers spoken in speech by users from recording using google speech to text. The config file written in python is below

```
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=44100,
        language_code="en-IN",
        speech_contexts = [{"phrases":["$00V_CLASS_FULLPHONENUMBER"]}]        
         )
```

How can i improve accuracy in number detection. Are there any other parameters that can be added. Also in many cases the first number in the speech is not getting detected. How can i avoid this.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices), there are some best practices to use the Speech to Text API. Two important ones are sample rate at `16000hrz` or higher and preferred format as `FLAC` or `LINEAR16`. In order to debug your case, could you provide the rest of the code and also elaborate more on your process? For instance, are are your files located in GCS? Are you getting any error output?

Comment: no, just numbers are not getting detected in some cases even when i feel they are clear.. I am using enhanced mode and model = phone no . so using 8000hrz as stated in documentation. This has improved the detection a bit

Comment: Could you provide the rest of your code ? Also, are your files in GCS? You mentioned the numbers are not being detected, could you tell me if this happens with all the audios or is it just a couple , where the quality of it may be lower?